# Check for unexpected exceptions using ScalaTest + ScalaCheck

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest, scalacheck, property-based-testing

I'm trying to write a property that basically states "it should either not throw an exception, or throw one of a list of possible exceptions" using ScalaTest and it's `GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks` which in turn uses scalatest. The issue is that I wasn't able to combine the `noException` with an logical or, so the best I could come with is this ugly test:

```
it should "not throw unexpected exceptions" in {
  forAll { (s: String) =>
    try { parse(s) }
    catch { case e:Throwable => e shouldBe a [ParsingFailedException] }
    true shouldBe true // prevent compile error
}}
```

What I would like to see instead would read more like

```
it should "not throw unexpected exceptions" in {
  forAll { (s: String) => {
    (noException should Be thrownBy) or (a [ParsingFailedException] shouldBe thrownBy) { parse(s)  }
}}
```

Comment: Is this difference non-deterministic? Because otherwise I'd suggest splitting your testing in two scenarios: one for when no exception should be thrown and one for one of the list should be thrown. In this way it's also clearer for other readers to know what should happen when

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we want to use the exception as a value and not to control an exceptional flow, we could use `scala.util.Try` and make assertions on the value of `Try`. So instead of calling `parse(s)` we could call `Try(parse(s))`.

Unfortunately, because the values are wrapped now, I can't think of a clean way to assert predicates on them other than writing a custom matcher. For your specific example, a custom matcher could look as follows:

```
class FailAsMatcher[E <: Throwable](t: Class[E]) extends Matcher[Try[Any]] {
  def apply(theTry: Try[Any]) =
    MatchResult(
      theTry.isFailure && (theTry.failed.get.getClass == t),
      s"did not fail as a $t",
      s"did fail as a $t"
    )
}
```

Since `Try` is covariant, we can define the generic type of our custom matcher to be `Try[Any]`. The matcher matches only instances of `Failure[Any]` that fail with an exception of the provided type. Now, we could call this as:

```
it should "not throw unexpected exceptions" in {
  forAll { (s: String) =>
    Try(parse(s)) should ( be ('success) or failAs(classOf[ParsingFailedException]))
  }
}

def failAs[E <: Throwable](t: Class[E]) = new FailAsMatcher[E](t)
```

Now, if a non-expected exception happens, the error could look as follows:

```
TestFailedException was thrown during property evaluation.
  Message: Failure(java.lang.NullPointerException) was not success, and did not fail as a class ParsingFailedException
```

Comment: Maybe we could change this to only take a generic parameter, i.e., `Try(parse(s)) should ( be ('success) or failAs[ParsingFailedException])` but I am not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't think about implemting a custom matcher :)